# neo4j / cypher - why is starting node excluded?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a simple graph:

[image]

When I run this simple query in neoeclipse:

```
START me=node:node_auto_index(name="Me") 
MATCH me-[:LIVES_IN]->()<-[:LIVES_IN]-(f)
RETURN f.name;
```

only my Girlfriend is returned!

Why am I excluded from the result?

```
Results
f.name  Girlfriend
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a path (what you specify in the match) will never contain the same relationship twice.
To find all the people living in the same location including yourself, you need to split into two actions, one finding your city and the other collecting people in this city using the `with` statement:

```
start me=node:node_auto_index(name='Me') 
match me-[:LIVES_IN]->homebase 
with homebase 
match homebase<-[:LIVES_IN]-people 
return people
```

See http://console.neo4j.org/?id=t0wjhg